# Illustrated book about a librarian, who is a book, traveling through the books of his library to protect his library from a foe

Tags: story-identification

Just trying to find the name of a book I read as a child. It was a fairly large illustrated book. Heres what I remember of the plot: It was a about a librarian or something similar, he himself was a book as were all of the characters. There was someone/something chasing him or trying to destroy his library and he was running through the books in his library, as in entering them and the story of each book would become reality. He also picked up a few companions on the way through the books. I hope someone knows this book as I'd love to know what it was called. As I said it was illustrated and I remember the illustrations being quite good. Thanks in advance

Comment: When did you read it, and in which language?

Answer (score 3):

The plot reminds of [The Pagemaster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Pagemaster) movie. They also mention at the wiki page that the film has several book adaptations -- the one by David Kirschner even won an Australian book award. Maybe it was one of those?